# Javascript: How do I change every word visible on screen?

Tags: javascript

I want to do a joke code that changes every word on screen by an specific other word, for example:
"I like trains" --> "hello hello hello"
Well, that's easy. The problem is to select every text on screen. Anyone can help me?

Comment: Recursively walk the DOM and modify every text node?

Comment: What have you tried so far? What is your code for the part that you say is "easy"? When you say "visible on screen" do you mean just words within that part of the document currently scrolled into view, or the whole of the current document?

Comment: var text = "I like trains";
var text2 = text.split(" ");
for (i=0; i < text2.length; i++) {
 text2[i] = "hello";
};
text2.toString().replace(/,/g," "); //Returns "hello hello hello"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recursively walk the nodes and do a regex replace. Quick and dirty example:

```
function replaceAllWords(newWord) {
    for (var i = 0; i < document.childNodes.length; i++) {
        checkNode(document.childNodes[i]);
    }
    function checkNode(node) {
        var nodeName = node.nodeName.toLowerCase();
        if(nodeName === 'script' || nodeName === 'style') {return;}
        if (node.nodeType === 3) {
            var text = node.nodeValue;
            var newText = text.replace(/\b\w+/g, newWord);
            node.nodeValue = newText;
        }
        if (node.childNodes.length > 0) {
            for (var j = 0; j < node.childNodes.length; j++) {
                checkNode(node.childNodes[j]);
            }
        }
    }
}

//Use like
replaceAllWords("Hello");
```

Doing a regex on innerHtml will replace anything that matches, including any block script thats on the page. This function checks that it is actually a text node, before doing a replace, the replace only does word characters (A-Za-z0-9_) that are 1 or more characters, so will not replace spaces or symbols (i.e. punctuation, $ etc will stay put)

Comment: Thanks mate, but it f*cks up the style of the page. Could you modify the code for keeping the style?

Comment: This code doesn't affect any of the styling directly. I suspect that the page is changing structure/layout/appearance due to all of its content changing, I mean you can't change every word on the page and expect all the paragraphs/divs/spans to all stay the same height / width. If there is floats in there it will probably drastically change. If you have a specific example I could take a look but to change all of the content on the page and analysis all of the style rules to ensure that the page looked identical after you change every word would be a monumental task

Comment: http://pastebin.com/S8N1jBGH
It changes the page style.

Comment: ah I see what you mean, that would be because it has inline style tags. I'll modify the code slightly to deal with inline style and script

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this?

```
var old = $('body').html();
$('body').html(old.replace('I like trains', 'hello hello'));
```

With Pure JS:

```
var new = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML.replace('I like trains','bye');
 document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML= new;
```

Comment: "I like trains" was an example, I want to change every word on the screen.

Comment: This answer is wrong, because it does not care about "text on screen". It replaces everything, scripts included.